# How can I auto-detect palette vs. truecolor png

Tags: perl, png, gd

As described in GD manual the following code always produces palette images:

```
$image = GD::Image->newFromPngData($mydata);
```

While the following produces truecolor images:

```
$image = GD::Image->newFromPngData($mydata,1);
```

However, what I want is to do some kind of auto detection:

Use palette for "8-bit colormap png" but use truecolor for "8-bit/color RGB png" files.

I expected this to be the default, but it is not.

I did not find a hint in libgd manual that this is possible. Would it be possible to extract this information from the data itself probably by manually reading the Information from the png header?

To make this more clear here is some code example which does not auto-detect anything:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use GD;

$image = GD::Image->newFromPng($ARGV[0]);

if ($image->isTrueColor()) {
  print "truecolor\n";
} else {
  print "indexed\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably possible to search the header of the file for what you want, but the results will probably be error prone.

Better to use a tool that can parse the header for you. A CPAN search reveals a few that might work well:

- [Image::ExifTool](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image%3a%3aExifTool)
- [Image::EXIF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image%3a%3aEXIF)
- [Image::PNG](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image%3a%3aPNG)

and others.

---

But from the GD docs, it seems like auto-detection is the default when the `newFromPngData` is only passed one argument:

> Images created by reading PNG images will be truecolor if the image
>   file itself is truecolor. To force the image to be palette-based, pass
>   a value of 0 in the optional $truecolor argument.

If auto-detection is not working for you, you should verify that your source files are indeed what you think they are, and if GD is interpreting them wrong, perhaps you should send in a bug report.